# Why am I receiving an 'sbserver not found' error when attempting to set up Google Safe Browsing Database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, safe-browsing, safe-browsing-api

I reached this [GitHub](https://github.com/google/safebrowsing/) repo. about google safe browsing database.

I have never used go, but I think it is required now. So I installed it using:

```
sudo apt install golang-go
```

Then, I followed the instructions in the GitHub page. I executed:

```
go get github.com/google/safebrowsing
```

But nothing installed in the path I was executing the command from. However, I proceeded to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Then the manual says, run the following command (which is two lines, I executed the first line, then I press enter, then nothing changes. Then executed the second line separately:

```
go get github.com/google/safebrowsing/cmd/sbserver
sbserver -apikey $APIKEY
```

After executing the second line, I got this error:

```
Command 'sbserver' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sxserver' from deb sx
  command 'sb_server' from deb spambayes
  command 'ssserver' from deb shadowsocks

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Can you please point to me what is wrong? How to install google safe browsing database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PATH is wrong. You will find `sbserver` in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Try `${GOPATH}/bin/sbserver -apikey $APIKEY`

If that does not work, then follow the Go installation instructions and make sure that your Go environment variables are correct.

GOPATH should look like `/home/myname/go` or something else that looks normal.

Your PATH should contain `${GOPATH}/bin`

Comment: Thanks. That help. But can you check my edit. What should I do next to query the DB? Am I doing it right so far?

Comment: I ave a long list of URLs. I want to automate testing each URL and save the original URL and the result in a file. Any hints on how to move forward with this?

Comment: @qbq - Remove your new edits from the question. Create a new question.

Comment: deleted. The new question in: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788050/how-to-check-a-list-of-urls-against-google-safe-browsing-database)